# Multiple PHP WHILE loops using the same query

Tags: php, mysql, loops

```
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM idevaff_affiliates";
$affiliateID = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());
```

This is my query above - I would like to use it for two WHILE loops

The first one is in the header section - setting up jquery

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($affiliateID)){
}
```

The second is used in a while loop in the body

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($affiliateID)){
}
```

Why can't I get it to work? - I did get it working but had to make two queries using the same SELECT info using two different variables.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Calling `mysql_fetch_assoc()` retrieves the next row (i.e., the next one you haven't already retrieved).  Once you've retrieved all the rows, it returns `false`.  So, once you've gotten through that first loop, you *have* retrieved all the rows, and all you'll get back is `false` every time!

If you need to reuse the same data twice, how about putting it all in an array?

```
$rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($affiliateID)){ 
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

Now you can iterate through `$rows` as many times as you like:

```
foreach($rows as $row) { ... }
```

Comment: @Wizzard's suggestion of `mysql_data_seek` to rewind the result set is a better option. Among other things, it won't use up a bunch of RAM on result sets like this answer will by storing each row in memory.

Answer (score 7):

This doesn't work because once you run through the result set once, the results internal pointer is at the end. To use it again you need to use mysql_data_seek before your second loop to reset the internal pointer to the beginning of the result set.

Answer (score 1):

You may seek the first row... using mysql_data_seek($affiliateID, 0), now you can do mysql_fetch_assoc() again... anyway, I prefer to load the result in an array.