# adding multiple do statements on a page using php and mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

Ok so I didn't see anything like this in the previous postings so if if has been covered before sorry for the repost.

I am trying to put a second do..while statement in the same page but when I do this it seems to drag down the page. it loads fine if I have only one statement in there but the minute I put in a second one it takes forever to load the page. I have a need of adding a total of 9 do..while statements which will most likely kill the page at this point. I'm not sure why it would be doing this any ideas?

The code I'm using is as follows

```
<p><?php
    do {
    $row_myContacts = mysql_fetch_assoc($myContacts);
    if ($row_myContacts['staffID'] != "81"){                                
    }
    else {
     echo $row_myContacts['firstName'] . " " . $row_myContacts['lastName'];?></p>
                  <p class="staff_title_national"><?php echo $row_nmyContacts['titleName'];?></p>
                  <br />
                  <li><?php echo $row_myContacts['address1'] 
. " " . $row_myContacts['address2'] ;?></li>
                  <li><?php echo $row_myContacts['cityName'] 
. ", " . $row_myContacts['state_abreviation'] . " " 
. $row_myContacts['zipCode'];?></li>
                  <br />
                  <li>Office: <?php echo format_phone($new_office_phone); ?></li>
                  <li>Fax: <?php echo format_phone($new_fax_phone); ?></li>
                  <br />
                  <br />
                  <li>E-Mail: 
<a href="<?php echo $row_myContacts['email'];?>"><?php echo $row_myContacts['email'];?></a></li>
                  <br />
           <?php }
    } while ($row_myContacts['staffID'] != '81')?>
```

I have tried testing it so that the staffID is == to the number i need, but it doesn't output anything. I think it should be that way but for some reason it doesn't work. and yes I moved the stuff in that variation so that the else was empty and the if had the information in it.

The page holds 4 sections of contacts under section 1 there is one section with 2 names (same address info) section 2 has 3 names different info, sections 3 and 4 have 2 each with different info. I even created 2 new tables in my database that reference the 4 sections if that helps. I do know my sql statement is correct it pulls all 9 contacts with their corresponding information.

/*edit below*/

so I also tried the code this way. and I do get it to load the first one but when I add a section for loop it shows nothing. I think it is because I am telling the loop to access the database at the same point that it left off so it isn't starting over on the loop.

```
<?php
            for ($x=$totalRows_myContacts; $x>=1; $x--){

                if ($row_myContacts['staffID'] == '81') {
                echo $row_myContacts['firstName'] . " " . $row_myContacts['lastName'];?></p>
                  <p class="staff_title"><?php echo $row_myContacts['titleName'];?></p>
                  <br />
                  <li><?php echo $row_myContacts['address1'] . " " . $row_myContacts['address2'] ;?></li>
                  <li><?php echo $row_myContacts['cityName'] . ", " . $row_myContacts['state_abreviation'] . " " . $row_myContacts['zipCode'];?></li>
                  <br />
                  <li>Office: <?php echo format_phone($new_office_phone); ?></li>
                  <li>Fax: <?php echo format_phone($new_fax_phone); ?></li>
                  <br />
                  <br />
                  <li class="emailTealGrey">E-Mail: <a href="<?php echo $row_myContacts['email'];?>"><?php echo $row_myContacts['email'];?></a></li>
                  <br />   

            <?php }$row_myContacts = mysql_fetch_assoc($Contacts);  
            }?>
```

so not sure how to tell the database to access itself again and start the query from the top I guess is what I need to do. any ideas how to tell it to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if there is no row for staffID=81
change code to something like this,

```
.....
do {
    $row_myContacts = mysql_fetch_assoc($myContacts);
    if ($row_myContacts == false){
        break;
    }
.....
```

Comment: ok so this sort of fixes my problem but now it won't find staff member 81 which is the one I need or any other staff member I put in there.

Comment: Check if your query returns staffID = 81. Also check if there is leading/trailing space in the returned value.

Comment: I am getting the 9 staff members including staff 81. like the for loop i added above it will display the first query but when i add a second one it shows empty. Do you know how to make the query start from the beginning instead of where it left off from the last one?

Comment: I don't know why you may want to iterate through the same result set more than once, but here is the solution: check this stackoverflow question [Multiple PHP WHILE loops using the same query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349900/multiple-php-while-loops-using-the-same-query)

Comment: ahh thank you yes that answers my question. and the reason is because I have a set of contacts that are not in a particular order and I need to find their staff information so that I can display it in different sections of the page.